# Recomposition is causing api to hit again and again in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I am doing pagination and have this code for my composable. But on recomposition the api is calling again and again.

```
{
composable(HomeSections.Todo.route) { from ->
            val mViewModel: TodosViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val uiState = mViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    
            Timber.i("Recomposition Logs >> HomeSections.Todo.route")
    
            val completedTodos =
                mViewModel.fetchCompletedTodos()
                    .collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    }
}
```

whenever i do any activity in my composable function the api is called multiple times because of the recomposition.

Comment: share more detailed code with ```ViewModel``` code so pictures get clear about the issue

Comment: viewmodel has nothing but a function in which I am calling the API. The main issue is my composable function.

Comment: You are observing state changes in ```composable``` which is not good practice. check out the state hoisting https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoistingv